# Python Split Array use For Loop to Mean every split and put it back together

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, split

I'm coding for an Coherence project and I'm now stuck at the problem to mean my array of values in splitted parts.

So ym task would be:
1. Take my array of values (R) split it in a certain number of array parts (split by epoch)
2. enter a loop to run it automatically.
3. in the loop every value of each split part of the original array should be avaraged

Maybe the solution is damn simple, but I got stuck and I miss the wood for the forest.

Here is my approach (Rxx, epochs are defined above):

```
epoch_Rxx = np.array_split(Rxx,epochs)
for i in range(0,epochs):
Rxx_mean = np.zeros(epochs)
Rxx_mean[i] = np.mean(Rxx[i])
```

---

In the end I want from the e.g. Rxx = 100 values  and epochs = 10

--> Rxx_mean = 10 values each to be the avaraged value of each epoch.

Greetings,

Daniel

Comment: Can you give a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? or show your expected output?

Comment: Whats the error that you're getting?

Comment: there is no error, but the for loop serves the  results of || array[0 ,0 ,0 ,0, 0.1521] for e.g. epoch is 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are after?

```
import numpy as np

Rxx = np.arange(100)
epochs = 10
Rxx_mean = []

epoch_Rxx = np.array_split(Rxx,epochs)
for i in range(0,epochs):
  Rxx_mean.append(np.mean(epoch_Rxx[i]))

print Rxx_mean
```